# Maven groovy-all change versions

Tags: maven, groovy

I have dependency in pom with groovy-all

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7</version>
            <type>pom</type>
   </dependency>
```

But if I check libs inside, I see 2.5.13 versions. How can I change all of this libs to 3.0.7? Of course I can add separately, but maybe is another option?

[image]

Comment: What change had you made? Are you using some sort of BOM or dependency
manipulating thing like e.g. comes with springboot?  Also please don't
use screenshots, where text would do.  We can not search in or copy from
screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The versions are managed in the `<dependencyManagement>` section of the POM, either directly or by using a BOM (scope import).

If you want to update them, you need to look there.

Comment: I added this version in <dependencyManagement> block but nothing changed. I can add only groovy-all version, but not version libs inside (for example groovy or groovy-json). I need override everyone in groovy-all lib

Comment: I did not mean you should _add_ it, but you should look inside the dependencyManagement (possibly of the parent POM) where the versions of all the groovy-libs are defined. And if you have found that source of the versions, you might be able to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing Groovy 2.5.13 elsewhere likely as a transitive dependency and maven is deciding to use 2.5.13 instead of 3.0.7.

Look at the groovy 3.0.7 pom:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/3.0.7/groovy-all-3.0.7.pom

It has no reference to 2.5.13.